# Как сделать дамп таблицы с только определёнными строками?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Вот у меня есть таблица `tab1`. Мне нужно с помощью PHP получить SQL-код добавления в эту же самую таблицу всех строк, где поле `key1` = `val1`. Это возможно как-то сделать?

Comment: Почитайте документацию на mysqldump, стандартную утилиту бекапа mysql. там среди прочих есть опция `--where='where_condition'`

Comment: @Mike а как к ней обращаться через php?

Comment: запускать с помощью system или popen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ответ из комментариев*

Можно воспользоваться утилитой `mysqldump` совместно с ключом `--where`. Запустить утилиту из PHP можно либо при помощи обратных кавычек, либо вызвав ее через функцию `system()`

```
<?php
`mysqldump dbname tab1 --where='key1 = "val1"' > report.sql`;
```